# csv to dictionary from urllib

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, urllib

With urllib i go to address that downloads a csv. I need to get the csv back as a Dictionary to the pycharm (and not as excel file).

dictionary keys are (as in the file) - Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume

I would appreciate your assistance.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen


with urlopen("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/aapl?period1=1640988000&period2=1657314000&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true&volume") as response:
    html = response.readline()


print(html)
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(html)` line?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import urllib2

url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/aapl?period1=1640988000&period2=1657314000&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true&volume'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

reader = csv.reader(response)
row1 = next(reader) 
dic = {}
for lines in reader:
    for i in range(len(row1)):
        if row1[i] not in dic:
            dic[row1[i]] = []
        dic[row1[i]].append(lines[i])
print(dic)
```

Im not sure, but I believe this is what something you are expecting, if not please feel free to comment. Thanks

Comment: thak you for your answer! Unfortunately I get an error -     No such file or directory: 'aapl.csv'         -  i added your code after mine

Comment: Actually I edited the code just now using urllib can you run the  entire code provided, it was working quiet good.

Comment: 'aapl.csv' is the file which is dowloaded locally in my system from the url you provided. But the latest code I provided is used `urllib` so you can run directly as separate python file. thanks

Comment: do you know why i get error like - row1 = next(str(reader))
TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator    ?  i dont have urllib2, so ijust do it with urllib.request.urlopen. cant download urllib2